# Is the following function closed under addition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the set of all functions on [0,1] of the form

$h(x) = \Sigma_{j=1}^na_je^{b_jx},$ where $a_j, b_j \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this set closed under addition? That is consider $f(x), g(x) \in \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}=\{\text{set of functions of the form h(x)}\}$. Is $f(x) + g(x) \in \mathcal{B}$?

I approached the question as follows:

$f(x)+g(x) = \Sigma_{j=1}^na_je^{b_jx} + \Sigma_{j=1}^nc_je^{d_jx} \neq \Sigma_{j=1}^n(a_j+c_j)e^{(b_j+d_j)x}$

Does the last inequality hold?

Comment: Am I right in thinking $n$ is fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you give does hold, but it does not necessarily prove what you say you want to prove. In general $e^a+e^b\not=e^{(a+b)}$.

The answer depends on whether or not $n$ is arbitrary. If it is arbitrary, then one could combine $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ into a sum of, say, length $2n$ which satisfies your definition. If $n$ is fixed then it is easy to find a counter example which would use your result to note that the sum of $f$ and $g$ cannot be written as a sum of n elements.